# Program crashes and I can't figure out why

Tags: c, crash

Program crashes and I can't figure out why. ptr and ptr1 are char** and each element of ptr and ptr1 is a char*, not all of the malloc'd space if full, however, leaving some null pointers in each. I think the problem is in this segment as the last thing printed is in this segment before crashing.

```
 while (strlen(ptr[k]) > 1 && strlen(ptr1[i]) > 1)
    {
        while ((strlen(ptr[k]) > 1 && strlen(ptr1[i]) > 1) && isFound == 0)
        {
            totalCounter++;
            lineCounter++;
            if(strcmp(ptr[k], ptr1[i]) == 0)
            {
                printf("'%s' is word %d in the list\n", ptr[k], lineCounter);
                isFound = 1;
            }
            k++;
        }
        if (isFound == 0)
            {
                printf("'%s' is not in the word list\n", ptr1[i]);
            }
        isFound = 0;
        lineCounter = 0;
        k = 0;
        i++;
        wordCounter++;
    }
```

Comment: regarding: `(strlen(ptr[k])`  and similar expressions:  since `ptr` is a pointer to a pointer, need code similar to `( strlen(*ptr)[k] )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You run out of valid array indices

you keep incrementing k in:

```
while ((strlen(ptr[k]) > 1 && strlen(ptr1[i]) > 1) && isFound == 0)
```

Add a check for k here, like

```
while ((strlen(ptr[k]) > 1 && strlen(ptr1[i]) > 1) && isFound == 0 && k < k_max)
```

same for i in

```
while (strlen(ptr[k]) > 1 && strlen(ptr1[i]) > 1)
```

Add a check for i here, like:

```
while (strlen(ptr[k]) > 1 && strlen(ptr1[i]) > 1 && i < i_max)
```

Comment: The program itself crashes, rather than due to an infinite loop

Comment: let's say k reaches 41 and you have only defined memory till 40, ptr1[k] will throw segmentation fault and crash.

Answer (score 1):

You did string length for a member of array, i.e. `strlen(ptr[k])`, this will try to evaluate the len for member available at position k of array p. So final processing will be

1. `strlen(ptr[0]);` //As k is initialized as 0,
   -> then it will be evaluated as
2. `strlen(0);` //As p is an array having elements `{0,1,2}`, so at 0th position, 0 is the element
   -> So, here `strlen` will try to evaluate length of type integer, which is out of scope for `strlen`

As `strlen` is a string function so, only string can be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following code through a C compiler.

```
#include <assert.h> //  Conditionally compiled macro that compares its argument to zero
#include <complex.h> // (since C99) Complex number arithmetic
#include <ctype.h> //   Functions to determine the type contained in character data
#include <errno.h> //   Macros reporting error conditions
#include <fenv.h> // (since C99)    Floating-point environment
#include <float.h> //   Limits of float types
#include <inttypes.h> // (since C99)    Format conversion of integer types
#include <iso646.h> // (since C95)  Alternative operator spellings
#include <limits.h> //  Sizes of basic types
#include <locale.h> //  Localization utilities
#include <math.h> //    Common mathematics functions
#include <setjmp.h> //  Nonlocal jumps
#include <signal.h> //  Signal handling
#include <stdalign.h> // (since C11)    alignas and alignof convenience macros
#include <stdarg.h> //  Variable arguments
#include <stdatomic.h> // (since C11)   Atomic types
#include <stdbool.h> // (since C99) Boolean type
#include <stddef.h> //  Common macro definitions
#include <stdint.h> // (since C99)  Fixed-width integer types
#include <stdio.h> //   Input/output
#include <stdlib.h> //  General utilities: memory management, program utilities, string conversions, random numbers
#include <stdnoreturn.h> // (since C11) noreturn convenience macros
#include <string.h> //  String handling
#include <tgmath.h> // (since C99)  Type-generic math (macros wrapping math.h and complex.h)
#include <time.h> //    Time/date utilities
#include <uchar.h> // (since C11)   UTF-16 and UTF-32 character utilities
#include <wchar.h> // (since C95)   Extended multibyte and wide character utilities
#include <wctype.h> // (since C95)
int main(){
  int ptr[]={0, 1, 2};
  int ptr1[]={3, 4, 5};
  int isFound=0;
  int wordCounter=0;
  int totalCounter=0;
  int lineCounter=0;
  int i=1;
  int k=0;
  while (strlen(ptr[k]) > 1 && strlen (ptr1[i]) > 1)
  {
  while ((strlen (ptr[k]) > 1 && strlen (ptr1[i]) > 1) && isFound == 0)
  {
    totalCounter++;
    lineCounter++;
    if (strcmp (ptr[k], ptr1[i]) == 0)
    {
      printf ("'%s' is word %d in the list\n", ptr[k], lineCounter);
      isFound = 1;
    }
    k++;
  }
  if (isFound == 0)
  {
    printf ("'%s' is not in the word list\n", ptr1[i]);
  }
  isFound = 0;
  lineCounter = 0;
  k = 0;
  i++;
  wordCounter++;
  }
}
```

here are errors I captured when I put it in the compiler.

> main.c:38:17: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strlen’ makes pointer
>   from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
>
> /usr/include/string.h:399:15: note: expected ‘const char *’ but
>   argument is of type ‘int’
>
> main.c:38:40: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strlen’ makes pointer
>   from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
>
> /usr/include/string.h:399:15: note: expected ‘const char *’ but
>   argument is of type ‘int’
>
> main.c:40:19: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strlen’ makes pointer
>   from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
>
> /usr/include/string.h:399:15: note: expected ‘const char *’ but
>   argument is of type ‘int’
>
> main.c:40:42: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strlen’ makes pointer
>   from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
>
> /usr/include/string.h:399:15: note: expected ‘const char *’ but
>   argument is of type ‘int’
>
> main.c:44:16: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer
>   from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
>
> /usr/include/string.h:144:12: note: expected ‘const char *’ but
>   argument is of type ‘int’
>
> segmentation fault
>
> program finished with exit code 139